# How to set a global variable with image coordinates in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, touch, global-variables

I'm currently using some standard Xcode to move an image around a view via touch control, I also want to set some global variables so that once i stop moving the image the x and y coordinates can be passed and used in another view. So far i have the following code where `Movegvarx` and `Movegvary` are the variables:

```
- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x ,
                                     recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
[recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0,0) inView:self.view];
Movegvarx = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2f", translation.x];
Movegvary = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2f", translation.y];

}
```

At the moment this doesn't seem to work, i.e. the global variables aren't set, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you made Movegvarx and y as a property and synthesized it? What you could do is make the image as the property of the class and you can ask it's coordinates.

Comment: Yes, I've synthesized it and still no luck. How would I go about setting the image as a property of the class and asking it's coordinates?

Comment: make the image the property. I assume you used a uiimageview?